# Converting a string to bytes

Tags: string, byte, ocaml

im fairly new to OCaml, so excuse any stupid mistake.

Im trying to modify the elements of a string, yet it wont allow me, saying it is expecting an expression of type bytes. After doing some reading, I know why, so I tried to convert my string to bytes, with no success. I've looked everywhere on how to convert a string to bytes, but can't seem to find anything. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

There is a function `Bytes.of_string` that does this.

```
Bytes.of_string "my string abc";;
- : bytes = Bytes.of_string "my string abc"
```

It's interesting to note that the toplevel expression printer (the P part of REPL) prints byte values using a `Bytes.of_string` call.

You can convert back to a string with `Bytes.to_string`.

```
# let b = Bytes.of_string "hal9000";;
val b : bytes = Bytes.of_string "hal9000"
# Bytes.to_string (Bytes.map (fun c -> Char.chr (Char.code c + 1)) b);;
- : string = "ibm:111"
```